# Vector norm - Understanding it's geometric meaning in regard to the Euclidean norm

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

I am trying to understand the vector norm. I have a few subquestions to the primary question here, what is the vector norm?

**1.** Firstly, lets take the Euclidean norm. Is then $\|x\|=d(x,0)$, where this is the Euclidean metric. Or do we allow vectors to sit anywhere in space, and $\|x\|$ is the length from the start of the vector to the end of the vector, sitting anywhere in space?

**2.** With the Euclidean norm, $\|x+y\|$ is the length of the vector $(x+y)$ right?

**3.** Let $X$ be a Euclidean space, If I have $\|x\|=1$, do I then have most of the vector, $x\in X$, , living inside of $S=\{a\in X| \quad\|a\|=1\}$, or do we treat the tip of the vector as the vector.

The confusion for $3.$ is that I was told to treat points in Euclidean space like vectors coming from the origin, and this has confused me since I first heard it.

---

I guess that's it, I can move forward for there I suppose and make a new question with follow ups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. $\|\vec{x}\|=d(X,0)$ is equivalent as "the length from the start of the vector to the end of the vector, sitting anywhere in space". I used $X$ because the components of $\vec{x}$ can be treated as the endpoint of the vector when it starts from the origin.

A vector can be translated to anywhere since it is determined by its length and direction. So for example, the vector $(1,1)$ can start from the origin and end at the point $(1,1)$, or it can start from $(2,3)$ and end at $(3,4)$, whereas its vector form is always $(1,1)$.

However, when you say $d(x,0)$, it is a bit abuse of notation. Since this $x$ is actually the end point $x$ when the vector is starting from the origin.

2. Yes.
3. This is the vector $\vec{x}$, so it could be any vector that has length $1$. But you can also treat them all like they start from the origin.

Comment: I have typed an extension question I will post in 4 minutes when I am allowed. Thanks :).

Comment: See here if you are willing :) : http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1394249/261529

Comment: @FunctionalAnalysis: I see that. Remember that when you write $\vec{x}$ in its vector form, it is already assumed to be starting from the origin, because the two components give you the $x,y$ coordinate of the end point when it starts from the origin. So that definition of the sphere is really saying that the endpoint of this vector is on the sphere WHEN IT STARTS FROM THE ORIGIN.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I think I am 75% comfortable now.

Comment: @FunctionalAnalysis: It takes some time to be comfortable with that from my own experience. :)