# Vector norm - Understanding the definition of the unit sphere

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces

If $\|x\|=1$ just means the vector $x$ has length one - Then why is the unit sphere defined as $S=\{x\in X| \quad \|x\|=1\}$?

let $X$ be a normed linear space with the Euclidean norm, then letting the vectors have their beginning at the origin works, but if $\|x\|=1$ just means the vectors lie anywhere in space and have length one, then I can't see why this gives a sphere.

Comment: If you wish to use the picture of vectors as "arrows", then you always assume they protrude from the origin. Those arrow-vectors that can be anywhere are different. They are either tangent vectors (localized to a point) or the vector space acting upon itself as a group of translations. Difference is sometimes not being made, since both of these can be identified with vectors from the original space, but the difference should be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a generalization of the spheres we already know.

Consider in $\Bbb R^3$ the norm given by $\|{\bf x}\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^3x_i^2$. Then the set $S = \{ {\bf x} \in \Bbb R^3 \mid \|{\bf x}\| = 1 \}$ is a sphere centered in the origin with radius $1$. In $\Bbb R^2$, we have that $S$ is a circle centered in the origin with radius $1$. If you consider in $\Bbb R^2$ the norm $\|{\bf x}\| = \max\{|x_1|,|x_2|\}$, the set $S$ is a square centered in the origin, with sides parallel to the coordinate axes and side $2$. And so on.

Comment: Can you review this answer in light of that, since this seems to be contradicting information http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394241/261529

Comment: Mainly I think I am confused, since $\|x\|=c$ seemingly gives us the distance from the origin, to the tip of $x$ where this length is $c$, and then what is $\|x+y\|$? The sum of two $2-$tuples defining the tips of two vectors, still the distance from the origin?

Comment: When you refer to norm, you only refer to length of a vector, so $||x+y||$ is just length of a vector starting at $0$ and ending at point $||x+y||$.

Comment: Don't rely too much on "arrows" and "tips". For example, would you interprete the matrices in ${\rm Mat}(n, \Bbb R)$ or functions in ${\scr C}\left(\left[a,b\right], \Bbb R \right)$ as arrows? General vector spaces generalize what we learn in $\Bbb R^3$, $\Bbb R^n$, etc.